# Mi programa me manda un error con el DataTable? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un form que contiene 2 textbox, un datagridview y 2 botones.(btn1 y bt2
en un textbox coloco el nombre de la hoja de excel que quiero buscar y con el boton 1 me abre el buscador de documentos y selecciono la hoja de excel que deseo abrir y me la muestra en el datagrid.

coloque el siguiende codigo:

```
public partial class Ejem2 : Form
{
    private BindingSource bindingsource1 = new BindingSource();
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("MI CONEXION");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //SqlCommandBuilder builder;
    public Ejem2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void GuardarXml( string xml)
    {
        // query sql
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_xml( xml) VALUES ( @xml)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MI CONEXION"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn))
        {
            // define parameters

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml, xml.Length).Value = xml;

            // open connection, execute query, close connection
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }


    private void LLenarGrid(string archivo, string hoja)
    {
        //declaramos las variables         
        OleDbConnection conexion = null;
        DataSet dataSet = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
        string consultaHojaExcel = "Select * from [" + hoja + "$]";
        //esta cadena es para archivos excel 2007 y 2010
        string cadenaConexionArchivoExcel = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + archivo + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        //para archivos de 97-2003 usar la siguiente cadena
        //string cadenaConexionArchivoExcel = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + archivo + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        //Validamos que el usuario ingrese el nombre de la hoja del archivo de excel a leer
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hoja))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay una hoja para leer");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //Si el usuario escribio el nombre de la hoja se procedera con la busqueda
                conexion = new OleDbConnection(cadenaConexionArchivoExcel);//creamos la conexion con la hoja de excel
                conexion.Open(); //abrimos la conexion
                dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(consultaHojaExcel, conexion); //traemos los datos de la hoja y las guardamos en un dataSdapter
                dataSet = new DataSet(); // creamos la instancia del objeto DataSet
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, hoja);//llenamos el dataset
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0]; //le asignamos al DataGridView el contenido del dataSet
                conexion.Close();//cerramos la conexion
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;       //eliminamos la ultima fila del datagridview que se autoagrega
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //en caso de haber una excepcion que nos mande un mensaje de error
                MessageBox.Show("Error, Verificar el archivo o el nombre de la hoja", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //el dataset tiene la funcion para obtener el string del XML

        //creamos un objeto OpenDialog que es un cuadro de dialogo para buscar archivos
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Archivos de Excel (*.xls;*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx"; //le indicamos el tipo de filtro en este caso que busque
        //solo los archivos excel
        dialog.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";//le damos un titulo a la ventana
        dialog.FileName = string.Empty;//inicializamos con vacio el nombre del archivo
        //si al seleccionar el archivo damos Ok
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //el nombre del archivo sera asignado al textbox
            textBox1.Text = dialog.FileName;
            string hoja = textBox2.Text; //la variable hoja tendra el valor del textbox donde colocamos el nombre de la hoja
            LLenarGrid(textBox1.Text, hoja); //se manda a llamar al metodo
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; //se ajustan las
            //columnas al ancho del DataGridview para que no quede espacio en blanco (opcional)
        }
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;// Conviertelo a un datatable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        string xml = ds.GetXml();//el dataset tiene la funcion para obtener el string del XM

    }

}
```

Lo que quiero es que al darle clic a mi btn2 me guarde los datos del datagridview en mi tabla de sql server, que contiene los campos id-(int, identity) y xml (xml), pero me manda el siguiente error:

> DataTable already belongs to another DataSet.

Comment: debes copiar el datatable.. ahi estas asignandolo a otro dataset, pero es el mismo datatable que ya esta abierto en un dataset anterior..

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje del exception esta claro, el datatable que recuperas desde el DataGridView esta en otra instancia, por eso no puede asignarlo a una nueva, salvo que realices algun clonado del objeto.

Podrias intentar usando

```
DataTable dtNew = dt.Copy();
ds.Tables.Add(dtNew);
```

[DataTable.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ya no me manda el error, pero no me guarda la informacion en la BD, estara bien la forma en la que lo coloque?

Comment: DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         
             DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;// Conviertelo a un datatable
            DataTable dtNew = dt.Copy();
            ds.Tables.Add(dtNew);
            string xml = ds.GetXml();//el dataset tiene la funcion para obtener el string del XM

Comment: El codigo del btn2 solo genera el xml, pero no realiza ningun INSERT a la tabla, no te estara faltando invocar el GuardarXml()